# PHP Header Location Change of Parent Frame

Tags: php, html, iframe, header, location

I have an iFrame that does some background processing. When this processing is complete I would like to re-direct the user to another page, but the header change code is only affecting the embedded iFrame. Is there a way to target the main window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen the deprecated [Meta redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) have a `target` attribute, but I don't know how widely it is supported.

In Javascript:

```
top.location.href = "resultpage.htm";
```

Works only if the top frame is on the same domain as the emitting page.

For a solution that works across domains and without Javascript, the following would work:

```
<a href="resultpage.htm" target="_top">Continue</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use JavaScript to track content of frame, if content change, redirect browser :)

Comment: how do I go about checking if the iFrame has changed? I thought onchange wouldn't work unless it's a form

Comment: Heare You have reference on how to retrieve content of frame, You can do an loop to check every peroid of time, if something has changed http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/get-the-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript-crossbrowser-solution-for-both-ie-and-firefox/

Answer (score 2):

We can use javascript like this:

```
target.window.location='locationpage.php';

parent.window.location='index.php';
```

Answer (score -2):

For me this always works without fail, have tried many of the others but there always seems to be some sort of issue....and it does not matter if headers have been sent etc.....

```
<?php

echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.google.com'</script>";

?>
```

Remember this goes at  the very bottom